# ListView does not load data from Curstom array adapter situated in separate java file

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-listview, android-adapter

I made two activities, one for listing the data and second activity is form for entering the data. For this, I used List and custom ArrayAdapter as I did it when putting the two displays in same activity. When the two displays are in same window, there is no problem. After I separated activities, I put the List and custom ArrayAdapter in separate java file so that I can access them from 2 activities.

I saved the data by calling static function

```
"addRestaurant(Restaurant r)"
```

from DetailForm.java. Custom Adapter RestaurantAdapter is made static so that it can fit in addRestaurant(Restaurant).After doing this, the data is saved but the ListView does not display them. Can any one help me here ?

/*************************MainActivity.java **************************/

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String ID_EXTRA="apt.tutorial._ID";
    RestaurantList restaurantlist = null;
    ListView list = null;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        restaurantlist = new RestaurantList(MainActivity.this);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        restaurantlist.setlistadapter(list);
    }

    @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){        
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.option) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailForm.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return (true);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

/*******************************DetailForm.Java ********************/

```
public class DetailForm extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText name=null;
    EditText address=null;
    EditText notes=null;
    RadioGroup types=null;
    String restaurantId=null;
    Restaurant current = null;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_form);

        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);
        notes=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.notes);
        types=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.types);
        Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

        save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
        restaurantId = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_EXTRA);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener(){ 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String type=null;
            current = new Restaurant();
            String newname = name.getText().toString();
            String newaddr = address.getText().toString();

            current.setName(newname);
            current.setAddress(newaddr);
            current.setNotes(notes.getText().toString());

            switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                case R.id.sit_down:
                    current.setType("sit_down");
                    break;
                case R.id.take_out:
                    current.setType("take_out");
                    break;
                case R.id.delivery:
                    current.setType("delivery");    
                    break;
            }
            RestaurantList.addRestaurant(current);  //adapter.add(current); // add values
            name.setText("");
            address.setText("");
            notes.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.ViewList) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DetailForm.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return (true);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

/*************************RestaurantList.java ***********************/

```
public class RestaurantList {
    List<Restaurant> model;
    static RestaurantAdapter adapter;

    public RestaurantList(Context context) {
        model  = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
        adapter = new RestaurantAdapter(context);
    }

    public void setlistadapter(ListView listview){
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public static void addRestaurant(Restaurant r){
        adapter.add(r);
    }

    public class RestaurantAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> {
        Context mycontext;

        RestaurantAdapter(Context context){
            super(context, R.layout.row, model);
            mycontext = context;
        }

        @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View row = convertView;
            RestaurantHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mycontext).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                holder = new RestaurantHolder(row);
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (RestaurantHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(model.get(position));
            return (row);
        }
    }

    public static class RestaurantHolder{
        private TextView name=null;
        private TextView address=null;
        private ImageView icon=null;

        RestaurantHolder(View row) {
            name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            address=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
            icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }

        void populateFrom(Restaurant r){
            name.setText(r.getName());
            address.setText(r.getAddress());
            if (r.getType().equals("sit_down")) {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_red);
            }
            else if (r.getType().equals("take_out")) {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_yellow);
            }
            else {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_green);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<Restaurant> model`is always empty that is why you are not able to see the `listView`

```
public class DetailForm  extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText etName;
EditText etAddress;
EditText etNote;
Button save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    etAddress= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    etNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.place);
    save= (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String name =etName.getText().toString();
    String address=etName.getText().toString();
    String notes= etNote.getText().toString();
    Restaurant restaurant=new Restaurant(name,address,notes);
            RestaurantList.addRestaurant(restaurant);
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, ListingActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Listing Activity

```
public class ListingActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new RestaurantAdapter(this,RestaurantList.getRestaurentsList()));
}
}
```

Restaurant

```
 public class Restaurant {
 String name;
 String address;
 String notes;
public Restaurant(String name, String address, String notes) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.notes = notes;

}
}
```

RestaurantAdapter

```
public class RestaurantAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List<Restaurant> mRestaurants;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public RestaurantAdapter(Context context, List restorentsList) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, restorentsList);
    mRestaurants = restorentsList;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RestaurantHolder holder = new RestaurantHolder();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        holder.name= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.address= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        holder.note= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.note);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RestaurantHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
 final Restaurant restaurant = mRestaurants.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(restaurant.name);
        holder.address.setText(restaurant.address);
        holder.note.setText(restaurant.notes);
    return (convertView);
}


public static class RestaurantHolder {
    private TextView name;
    private TextView address;
    private TextView note;
}
}
```

RestaurantList

```
public class RestaurantList {
private static List<Restaurant> restaurants=new ArrayList<>();
public static void addRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
    restaurants.add(restaurant);
}

public static List<Restaurant> getRestaurentsList()
{
    return restaurants;
}
}
```

I have provided the snippens for all the operations hope this helps

Comment: I edited the code as you said but still it didn't work.

Comment: please refer to some tutorial on implementing listview with adapter, basically the method listview.setAdapter(adapter); should be a method on your listing activity, and holding static reference to adapter is not good

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you start a "new MainActivity" when you click on ViewList in your menu instead of back to the "original MainActivity" (if don't get it, press back button after Saved :) ). If you really want to make the least changes to see the result, change your `onOptionsItemSelected()` in `DetailForm`:

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.ViewList) {
        finish();
    }
    return true;
}
```